# using routes in Codeigniter to get to one of two controllers

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I have two controllers Configure.php and Users.php. In my routes.cfg I have:

```js
$route['default_controller'] = 'Users/login';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
$route['registration'] = 'registration';
$route['login'] = 'login';
$route['subit_backend']['GET']='subit_backend/register';
$route['save_userinput']='Users/save_userinput';
```

When a user brings up the website the following page comes up in the browser bar https://www.stantiation.com/sub_crud/Users/login/ which is perfect.

The problem is that if a user has forgotten their password I am having trouble routing them to method where they can create a new one. I have the user send an email to themselves where I have placed a "code" that will allow them to update their password. The email has a link to this form:
https://www.stantiation.com/sub_crud/Users/resetPassword?fp_code=492c8bbd3841xxx8201f3a01d77fd.

I also have a view file called view/Users/resetPassword.php which is form that allows the user to enter a new password. That pops up fine. This is the post method of the form.
      
When the user presses submit, I get https://www.stantiation.com/sub_crud/Users/save_userinput in the toolbar and a 404 error, because there is no save_userinput.php file. I am trying to get the save_userinput() method in the Users.php controller to run, not  save_userinput.php in the view/Users/directory. I agree with the 404 because that file doesn't exist.
How can I specify in a form that I want the method in controller Users, not the file view/Users/save_userinput.php? That is why I put the last $route in but that doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you might be understanding the CodeIgniter URL scheme. Read about it [HERE](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html).

Basically, it boils down to `http:doman.tld/controller/function[/var1 ...[/varN]]`
So, after the domain you have multiple segments that are interpreted like so:

1. The first segment represents the controller that should be invoked.
2. The second segment represents the class function, or method, that should be called.
3. The third, and any additional segments, represent any variables that will be passed to the controller.

So the URL `https://www.stantiation.com/sub_crud/Users/save_userinput` would go to the controller `Users` (which appears to be in the folder of `/application/controllers/sub_crud`) and call the controller method `save_userinput`. It is not looking for a file named `save_userinput.php`.

The 404 could be because the controller is not in a sub-folder or because some other file the controller tries to load, i.e. a "view" file, cannot be found.

It's hard to offer better advice without seeing the html for the form and knowing exactly how you have your file layout structured.

(*Side note: I avoid putting controllers in sub-folders because it messes with the URL "look" and IMO, in terms of "controllers", it's not that hard to track what-is-what.*)

You really only need routes when you want to override CodeIgniter's segment-based approach to URLs. With that in mind, it appears (based on a general lack of understanding about your app) that the following "routes" don't make sense.

```
$route['registration'] = 'registration';
$route['login'] = 'login';
$route['subit_backend']['GET']='subit_backend/register';
$route['save_userinput']='Users/save_userinput';
```